# Show that $e^z-az^n=0$ has exactly $n$ zeros in $B(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}, |a|>e, n\in\mathbb{N_1}$

I have to show that $e^z-az^n=0$ has exactly $n$ zeros in $B(0,1)$

---

First, $f(z)=e^z$ and $g(z)=-az^n$ are entire.

On $\partial B(0,1)$ we have $|g(z)|=|a|$

On $\partial B(0,1)$ we also have that $|\operatorname{Re}z| \le 1$

So we have

$$|g(z)|=|a|\ge e^{\operatorname{Re}z}=|f(z)|$$

because we assumed $|a|>e$

Now from Rouche theorem $g(z)$ has the same number of zeros in $B(0,1)$ as $f(z)+g(z)$. Thus the equation $e^z-az^n=0$ has exactly $n$ zeros.

Correct?

Comment: changed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost correct, but there is one small detail that I think needs to be addressed.

You showed that $|g(z)| \geq |f(z)|$ on $\partial B(0, 1)$ and then concluded that $g$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeroes in $B(0, 1)$. But this does not follow from Rouche's Theorem; the theorem requires $|g(z)| > |f(z)|$ on $\partial B(0, 1)$, not $|g(z)| \geq |f(z)|$. Luckily, your manipulations (suitably written) do in fact establish the desired inequality:

$$|g(z)| = |a| > e \geq e^{\operatorname{Re}z} = |f(z)|.$$

Comment: good point! thanks